# Ubuntu Bionic server not responding to ping/SSH

Tags: server, 18.04, sshd

Things I've tried.

- I checked and verified the server can connect outside by pinging my WiFi router and desktop. No issues there. As another test, I installed a package via apt.
- I checked and verified that ufw is inactive/not running. I believe ufw is the firewall.
- I cannot ping the server from my desktop. But I can ping the desktop from my server.
- I verified SSHD is running via systemctl status sshd.
- I believe by default SSHD is listening to all requests from all IPs (0.0.0.0). As a test, I changed added this line: Listen: 192.168.1.5 and restarted the server. Same results. I cannot SSH to the server

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: *"I cannot ping the server from my desktop"* that sounds like a networking issue - either a routing problem or something more subtle like a conflicting IP address